# mongoose - enable `toJSON` for specific virtuals

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a mongoose model with a bunch of virtual properties, if I do `model.toJSON({ virtuals: true })` all of them will be in the JSON.

Is it possible for me to only do this for particular virtual properties? So instead of all of them a select few will be in the JSON.